# Delete message from jabber history in Empathy 3.2

Tags: empathy, delete, log, history, jabber

I accidentially sent a message with private information to a friend of mine on Jabber (using Empathy 3.2).

I now want to delete this message from the history, but I cannot find where Empathy 3.2 stores the logs.

Please help me!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

found it on
http://live.gnome.org/Empathy/FAQ#Where_does_Empathy_save_files_.28accounts.2C_logs.2C_configuration.29.3F

It's stored in ~/.local/share/TpLogger/logs

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For me this is the right path  "~/.purple/logs/jabber" for remove old converstions.